# jQuery: show Div when check first radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the example below, I'm trying to show a specific div only when i check the radio button "yes".

It's ok for one div but when I try to do this for two separate panes, checking the second radio button also expands the first field.

How can I fold/unfold each container separately?

https://jsfiddle.net/vsf7mph8/3/

```js
 $('.row .otherRowinput').hide();

 $('[type=radio]').on('change', function () {
  if($('.form-radio input:nth-child(1)').val() == $(this).val() ||$('.form-radio input:nth-child(2)').val() == $(this).val())
  $('.otherRowinput').toggle('fast');
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="form-group mb-0">
<label for="one">question A</label> 
<div class="form-radio">
 <div class="radio radio-inline">
  <label>
   <input type="radio" name="one" class="showOtherFiled" >
   <i class="helper"></i>yes
  </label>
 </div>
 <div class="radio radio-inline">
  <label>
   <input type="radio" name="one">
   <i class="helper"></i>no
  </label>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

  <div class="col-md-12 otherRowinput">
 <div class="form-group">
    <textarea id="my1" name="my1"  type="text" class="form-control">
      
    </textarea>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="form-group mb-0">
<label for="two">question B</label> 
<div class="form-radio">
 <div class="radio radio-inline">
  <label>
   <input type="radio" name="two" class="showOtherFiled" >
   <i class="helper"></i>yes
  </label>
 </div>
 <div class="radio radio-inline">
  <label>
   <input type="radio" name="two">
   <i class="helper"></i>two
  </label>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

  <div class="col-md-12 otherRowinput">
 <div class="form-group">
    <textarea id="my1" name="my1"  type="text" class="form-control" required></textarea>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mre] (this means, your _code must be in the question itself, as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/4642212)_), and demonstrate _your research and your attempts_ and explain what precisely didn’t work. See [How to create Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/4642212).

Comment: The messaging wanted you to put the code in the question. Stackoverflow has snipplets.

Comment: I included the external minimal example into your question and rephrased the question to make the question clearer (in my perception) I hope I understand you correctly

Comment: thanks All . please check it now

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is that `$('.otherRowinput').toggle('fast');` applies to **all** text fields. However, you only want to apply it to the **nearest** text field.

For this, don't use the `$(selector)` function which applies to all objects in the DOM, but traverse the DOM starting from the checkbox that was modified. Starting from the currently checked box, traverse the DOM upwards until you find a common parent of the checkbox and the textarea, then traverse it downwards to the text area and toggle that.

You find the parent that includes both the checkbox and the text field with `$(this).closest(selector)`. Then, starting from that parent object, select the text area that is a child of that element using `find(selector)`. In total:

```
$(this).closest(".row").find(".otherRowinput").toggle('fast');
```

Below is your updated example.

```js
$('.row .otherRowinput').hide();

 $('[type=radio]').on('change', function () {
  if($('.form-radio input:nth-child(1)').val() == $(this).val() ||
       $('.form-radio input:nth-child(2)').val() == $(this).val()){
         $(this).closest(".row").find(".otherRowinput").toggle('fast');
       }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="form-group mb-0">
<label for="one">question A</label> 
<div class="form-radio">
 <div class="radio radio-inline">
  <label>
   <input type="radio" name="one" class="showOtherFiled" >
   <i class="helper"></i>yes
  </label>
 </div>
 <div class="radio radio-inline">
  <label>
   <input type="radio" name="one">
   <i class="helper"></i>no
  </label>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

  <div class="col-md-12 otherRowinput">
 <div class="form-group">
    <textarea id="my1" name="my1"  type="text" class="form-control">
      
    </textarea>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="form-group mb-0">
<label for="two">question B</label> 
<div class="form-radio">
 <div class="radio radio-inline">
  <label>
   <input type="radio" name="two" class="showOtherFiled" >
   <i class="helper"></i>yes
  </label>
 </div>
 <div class="radio radio-inline">
  <label>
   <input type="radio" name="two">
   <i class="helper"></i>two
  </label>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

  <div class="col-md-12 otherRowinput">
 <div class="form-group">
    <textarea id="my1" name="my1"  type="text" class="form-control" required></textarea>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks bro :)   but the div always show on click on both options

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you mean. There are multiple div's and multiple options. Which div shows when clicking on which option and what do you want instead?